# Access violation Fmx280.bpl

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

Just recently installed Rad Studio 11.2/Delphi, at first all went just fine.
But now i have error "access violation at address in module fmx280.bpl" on any action with firemonkey elements.

Creating new project, adding camera component or any other connected with FM (no any code), trying to delete it (or close form), boom! error. Tried to delete Rad Studio, clean folders, etc.

Providing error message

```
[6B94CE75]{fmx280.bpl  } FMX.Media.TCaptureDevice.StopCapture (Line 885, "FMX.Media.pas" + 1) + $2
[6B94D72E]{fmx280.bpl  } FMX.Media.TCameraComponent.DoStop (Line 1226, "FMX.Media.pas" + 1) + $7
[6B94D325]{fmx280.bpl  } FMX.Media.TCameraComponent.Destroy (Line 1125, "FMX.Media.pas" + 1) + $2
[6F93FDF4]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TObject.Free (Line 17991, "System.pas" + 1) + $4
[6F330916]{designide280.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.DeleteSelection (Line 5231, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 44) + $2
[6F37769F]{designide280.bpl} Surface.TDesignSurface.DeleteSelection (Line 214, "Surface.pas" + 0) + $7
[6F2F3E47]{designide280.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DeleteSelection (Line 792, "Designer.pas" + 2) + $5
[6F2F66A7]{designide280.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.Key (Line 1612, "Designer.pas" + 4) + $3
[678ADD35]{fmxdesigner280.bpl} FmxSurface.KeyEvent (Line 6764, "FmxSurface.pas" + 8) + $21
[678AE21F]{fmxdesigner280.bpl} FmxSurface.TFmxDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 6891, "FmxSurface.pas" + 43) + $6
[6B70F99D]{fmx280.bpl  } FMX.Platform.Win.WndProc (Line 2205, "FMX.Platform.Win.pas" + 9) + $23
[6EA32A28]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.SendAppMessage (Line 3804, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 2) + $4
[6EA37B7C]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7362, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[6EA3F760]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CNKeyDown (Line 12326, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 11) + $C
[6EA37F46]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7584, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[678BCAEA]{fmxdesigner280.bpl} FmxFormContainer.TControlSizer.ControlWndProc (Line 1885, "FmxFormContainer.pas" + 94) + $36
[6FA5580C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18490, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[6EB8417F]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11460, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[6EB841C2]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 11490, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[6EB84501]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 11629, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 27) + $3
[00AF8082]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 227, "" + 16) + $2
```

Comment: From what I can tell this is a known bug and it has been addressed in 11.2 Patch 1 https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-11-2-alexandria-patch-1-available/

Comment: Wow, installed patch and problem gone. I dunno why i havent seen patch before. Thx a lot!